# Implement movie with MobileVLCkit in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, media-player, vlc, xcode8.2, movieplayer

Now, I'm using ***mobilevlckit*** library for my project. 
[image]

Currently, the problem is that I don't know how to implement **player slide bar button** in mobilevlckit. Whatever I drag the slidebar, the video does not forward/backward. 
Another problem is that **Movie Duration** Label. It cannot show counting the movie time. It can shows only the total duration of the movie.

I'm implementing this with Swift 3.

Comment: I have this problem too.

Comment: @May Phyu how you are updating the media players position..! Can you show your code. I think so player position should be change between 0 to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I set

```
slider value = 0.5
slider maximum = 1
slider minimum = 0
```

It's worked in my project.